# How do I emit a $ literal in front of an interpolated value in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

I have a Terraform string. It could be a `var.` or a `local.` or an output of some resource. I want to interpolate that string into another string with `$` in front. Unfortunately,

```
"$${var.my_string}"
```

doesn't work because `$${var.my_string}` is the escape sequence that tells Terraform not to interpolate `var.my_string`.

How do I join `$` onto the front of an interpolated value?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to interpolate two strings: the string `"$"` and the string you want:

```
"${"$"}${var.my_string}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to @James' own answer, here are couple more ways to do it:

1. Unicode character [escape sequence](https://github.com/hashicorp/hcl/blob/main/hclsyntax/spec.md#template-expressions) (`0024` is the [code](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/) for `$`): `"\u0024${var.my_string}"`
2. A [strip marker](https://github.com/hashicorp/hcl/blob/main/hclsyntax/spec.md#template-literals) in the interpolation: `"$ ${~var.my_string}"`

> When a strip marker is present, any spaces adjacent to it in the corresponding string literal (if any) are removed before producing the final value.